# Three columns in two tables to four columns in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, union

I'm trying to combine two tables, each has three columns and two of those are common.  The `income` table has `Location`, `date` and `Amt_recd`, the `expense` table has `Location`, `date` and `Amt_spent`.  I want to combine these two tables so there is one table with four columns, and any common dates are combined to one row.  I've tried this:

```
select location, date, amt_recd, null as amt_spent
from income

union

select location, date, null as amt_recd, amt_spent
from expense
```

And it gets me just one step away, since it does not combine like dates into one row, it has two rows where `amt_recd` is `null` in  one and `amt_spent` is `null` in the other.  What is a better way to construct this so I get a result that is more condensed?  I've tried various joins instead of union, and haven't been able to get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: What joins have you tried and what was wrong with the results you got?

Comment: I tried an inner join on location, that was way too many rows.  I tried full outer join on both location and date as Murienek recommended below, but that gave me a bunch of rows with values only in the "exp" column, and didn't include dates that exist only in the expense table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am basing this answer on this line from your original post:

> I want to combine these two tables so there is one table with four
>   columns, and any common dates are combined to one row.

The second half of that suggests that you need not only a JOIN, but also to aggregate.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(i.location, e.location) AS Location
, COALESCE(i.[date], e.[date]) AS [date]
, SUM(i.amt_recd) AS amt_recd
, SUM(e.amt_spent) AS amt_spent
FROM income I
FULL OUTER JOIN expense e
  on i.location = e.location
  and i.date = e.date
GROUP BY 
  COALESCE(i.location, e.location)
, COALESCE(i.[date], e.[date])
```

This will give you one row per unique combination of location & date.

If you really need to further reduce the results to one row per date, you will need to specify rules for which location to show when there is more than one location on a given date.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the combination of (location, date) is unique in each table, you are correct in stating that `union` is the wrong tool for the job, and looking into `join`s instead. Since you may have incomes without expenses or expenses without incomes, a `full outer join` is in order:

```
SELECT i.location, i.date, i.amt_recd, e.amt_spent
FROM income i
FULL OUTER JOIN expense e ON i.location = e.location AND i.date = e.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to join the two tables pretty easily.

```
select i.location, i.date, i.amt_recd, e.amt_spent
from income i
inner join expense e
on i.location = e.location
and i.date = e.date
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't quite get what I'm looking for.  There are also some dates in the expense table that are unique.  I need one row for each date that's on either table (not necessarily both), with a value in each of the last two columns if there's income and expense on that day, or one value and null for the other if there's only one of the two on that date.  This only gets me the days where both exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `JOIN` the tables

```
select i.location, i.date, i.amt_recd as amt_recd, e.amt_spent as amt_spent
from income i
full outer join expense e
on i.location = e.location
and i.date = e.date
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't quite get what I'm looking for. There are also some dates in the expense table that are unique. I need one row for each date that's on either table (not necessarily both), with a value in each of the last two columns if there's income and expense on that day, or one value and null for the other if there's only one of the two on that date. This only gets me the days where both exist

Comment: Using a join is correct, but I think you'll want to use a FULL OUTER JOIN instead.